# netcat / named pipe proxy over ssh

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, netcat, named-pipes

I am used to forwarding a remote service port on localhost using ssh like:

`ssh -L 2181:localhost:2182 user@server`
(forward remote host port 2182 to local port 2181)

now, from the machine I ssh to, I am trying to reach a tcp service and forward the response to my local machine:

`local-machine:2181 <-- SSH --> remote-machine:2182 <-- netcat/named pipe --> service:2181`

Note: I do not have direct access to the service machine, I only have access to the network through the machine I SSH to.

I was trying to use netcat with a named pipe:

On the remote-machine:

```
mkfifo fifo
nc -k -l 2182 <fifo | nc service 2181 >fifo
```

On local machine: 
`echo message | nc localhost 2181`

but that doesn't seem to work.

I also tried, on remote-machine
`nc -k -l 2182 0<fifo | nc service 2181 1>fifo`

without luck

On the remote machine `nc -k -l 2182` outputs the message I send from the local-machine:2181

if I simply pipe this like: `nc -k -l 2182 | nc service 2181` 
I do see the response from the service on the remote-machine. So I'm able to go all the way to the service and back to the remote-machine but it stops there:

`local-machine:2181 <-/- SSH --> remote-machine:2182 <-- netcat --> service:2181`

so I don't understand why the named pipe won't forward the response through the ssh connection back to my local machine.

`echo message | nc localhost 2182` on the remote-machine does NOT output anything back on the local-machine, so it's not making it through SSH for some reason.

Any idea why this is and how to fix it?

Thanks for help.

(EDITED for clarity)
Note: I need this because I can only SSH to one machine, which is part of a cluster, and that machine has access to the service(s). I do not want to expose the service to the outside, nor have SSHD one every service container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was pointed to the fact that one can simply do

`ssh -L 2181:service:2181 user@remote-machine`

to forward the connection to `service` from `remote-machine` to the port on `local-machine`.

simple and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use -R for this purpose:

```
ssh -R 8080:127.0.0.1:7070 yourhost
```

This will open a port on yourhost:7070 that forwards to localhost:8080

Documentation says

```
[-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
```